# 'Shell': identifier not found

Tags: c++-cli

I get this when trying to execute this C++ program.  Why?

The code is:

```
private: 
    System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        Shell("maplestory.exe")
```

Comment: Perhaps you want `System.Shell.execute()`?

Comment: well it soolved but when i look on tuts on youtube when people doeble click on a button they get a short code what start as Private Sub Button1_click... and when i click i get everything in total. u know how to fix?

Comment: when they open they get form1.vb when i open i get form1.h

Comment: It must be a tutorial on VB.NET - they are programming in VisualBasic. You are programming in C++/CLI.

Answer (score 0):

You either need [System.Shell.execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms723232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from the .NET library or you need to call the Windows API [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: well it soolved but when i look on tuts on youtube when people doeble click on a button they get a short code what start as Private Sub Button1_click... and when i click i get everything in total. u know how to fix?

Comment: @GlennHulscher - it seems you are talking about the IDE, rather than the actual execution of your program? What IDE are you using?

Comment: microsoft visual C++ Express 2010

Comment: @GlennHulscher The tutorials are probably "Microsoft Visual Basic" tutorials not "Visual C++" tutorials. If you want to program Microsoft Visual Basic, use Microsoft Visual Basic Express 2010.